# Meaning of "caps not pop with watch crystal" in a schematic

Tags: pcb, schematics, manufacturing

[image]

> caps not pop with watch crystal

You can find this sentence in [ADuC 841 evaluation board schematic](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/363997658ADuC_SAR_PCB_A3.pdf). Could someone explain what does it mean?

Comment: If you don't put in a watch crystal the capacitors might explode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ADuC 841 integrated circuit will work with either of two alternative crystals. The ADuC 841 evaluation board (for which the schematic notes have precipitated the question) has therefore been designed to take either of those crystals. It has footprints for capacitors C17/18, which depending on which crystal is fitted can be either populated or left unpopulated.

If you fit the 11MHz one, you must also fit the capacitors.

If you fit the 32768Hz one (a 'watch' crystal) you must not fit the capacitors. Pop is an abbreviation for populate.

Comment: I guess my answer was not clear enough?

Comment: Neil also notes that the user must use ONE of the crystals, an information which the OP seems to have missed, so I guess his answer is more complete.

Comment: I find Neil's answer to be simpler and more comprehensive. I didn't missed the fact that only one crystal must be used -- it wouldn't make sense to have both of them.

Comment: Anyway thank you both, as non-native english speaker (and electronics hobbyist) I would never guess that "pop" is for populate ;)

Comment: @AleksanderZ. No point in keeping the answer that's not useful to the OP then.

Comment: @Armandas: The "pupulated" spelling didn't help your cause either. ;^)

Comment: @ACD fixed your fix! I did intend to talk about the board in my first draft answer, it is the thing that is populated or not with capacitors. Of course the only reason the board is like that is because it's what the IC requires.